# Add indexes of all occurrences of character in a string to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, indexof

I'm trying to add all of the indexes of a specific character to an array from a string.

I've got the following code, but I've had to restart my browser about 10 times because it doesn't work.

```
var xPositions = new Array();
var startPos = 0;
var string = "abcdexabcdexabcdexabcdexabcdexabcdexabcdex";

while (true) {

    var currentIndex = string.indexOf("x", startPos);

    if (currentIndex == -1) {
        break;
    }

    xPositions.push(currentIndex);
    startPos = currentIndex;

}
```

I thought about iterating forever until there are no more occurrences of the character, and then break.

Any help/suggestions appreciated.

Comment: `startPos = currentIndex+1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var currentIndex = string.indexOf("x", startPos+1);
```

I think you're getting the same current index over and over. "indexOf" begins its search at the index you specify, so you must increment it relative to the last find.

For future reference, you may consider trying to use a debugger with breakpoints, problems like this become relatively easy to spot (even just doing a few console.log's of relevant data can make mincemeat out of this type of bug - it's hard to always perfectly understand how a function you've never used before will work, there's no shame in seeing if it's behavior matches your expectations).